# Highcharts tooltip multivalues when X is a constant

Tags: charts, highcharts

There are no possibility to see ToolTip on irregular chart when some points placed on the same X line but with different Y values.

[image: Problem example]

actually I expected observe tooltip in that places where mouse positioned and if the graph Point exist in the small radius around. However for the picture above we can observed tooltip only for the higest and pre-higest points, but not for the lowest and pre-lowes points.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, duplicated points on xAxis are not supported for (sp)line series. You can use scatter series with `lineWidth: 1` instead.